# 'ApplicationDto' does not contain a definition for 'Applications'

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

The task is to create the .NET Core API for applications accounting. The application is an entity with the fields Id, Title, Description, Status. In the last controller class, there is the [HttpPost ()] method to create a new application, and the Id must be determined automatically, according to the maximum value from the Data class received after the selection. Tell me, please, how to define the **Applications** variable from the controller class (in the ApplicationDto class)? **Errors:**

**Error 1:** 'ApplicationDto' does not contain a definition for 'Applications' and no extension method 'Applications' accepting a first argument of type 'ApplicationDto' could be found

**Error 2:** The name 'Applications' does not exist in the current context AppsAccounting

**Code:**

```
namespace AppsAccounting
{
    public class ApplicationsDataStore
    {
        public static ApplicationsDataStore Current { get; } = new ApplicationsDataStore();

        public List<ApplicationDto> Applications { get; set; }

        public ApplicationsDataStore()
        {
            Applications = new List<ApplicationDto>()
            {
                new ApplicationDto()
                {
                    Id = 1,
                    Title = "Application 1",
                    Description = "A New Application has been created",
                    Status = "New"
                },

                new ApplicationDto()
                {
                    Id = 2,
                    Title = "Application 2",
                    Description = "The Application is in progress",
                    Status = "In Progress"
                },

                new ApplicationDto()
                {
                    Id = 3,
                    Title = "Application 3",
                    Description = "The Application has been completed",
                    Status = "Completed"
                },

                new ApplicationDto()
                {
                    Id = 4,
                    Title = "Application 4",
                    Description = "The Application was canceled",
                    Status = "Canceled"
                },

                new ApplicationDto()
                {
                    Id = 5,
                    Title = "Application 5",
                    Description = "The Application was rejected by some reasons",
                    Status = "Rejected"
                },

                new ApplicationDto()
                {
                    Id = 6,
                    Title = "Application 6",
                    Description = "The Application was suspended by some reasons",
                    Status = "Suspended"
                }
            };
        }
    }
}


namespace AppsAccounting.Models
{
    public class ApplicationDto
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace AppsAccounting.Models
{
    public class ApplicationForCreationDto
    {
        public string Title { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
    }
}


namespace AppsAccounting.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/applications")]
    public class ApplicationsController : Controller
    {
        [HttpGet()]
        public IActionResult GetApplications()
        {
            return Ok(ApplicationsDataStore.Current.Applications);
        }

        [HttpGet("{id}", Name = "GetApplication")]
        public IActionResult GetApplication(int id)
        {
            var applicationToReturn = ApplicationsDataStore.Current.Applications.FirstOrDefault(a => a.Id == id);

            if (applicationToReturn == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(applicationToReturn);
        }

        [HttpPost()]
        public IActionResult CreateApplication([FromBody] ApplicationForCreationDto application)
        {
            if (application == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            var maxApplicationId = ApplicationsDataStore.Current.Applications.SelectMany(
                a => a.Applications).Max(a => a.Id);

            var finalApplication = new ApplicationDto()
            {
                Id = ++maxApplicationId,
                Title = application.Title,
                Description = application.Description,
                Status = application.Status
            };

            Applications.Add(finalApplication);

            return CreatedAtRoute("GetApplication", new
            { id = finalApplication.Id }, finalApplication);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The full namespace name is

```
HttpContext.Current.Application["ApplicationToken"]
```

Make sure you have a reference to System.Web.dll